# Scala functional programming operator :::

Tags: scala, functional-programming, operators

First i have type declaration for binary tree:

```
sealed trait BT[+A]
case object Empty extends BT[Nothing]
case class Node[+A](elem:A, left:BT[A], right:BT[A]) extends BT[A];;
```

And further i have this code for inorder traversal with this mystery looking operator " ::: ".

What does this operator " ::: " exactly mean in this code?

```
def inorder[A](tree: BT[A]): List[A]  = {
  tree match {
  case Node(v,l,r) =>(inorder(l)) ::: (v::(inorder(r))) 
  case Empty => Nil
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a method of `scala.collection.immutable.List` and what it does is concatenate lists. Example:

```
scala> List(1,2) ::: List(3,4,5)
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

See the [API documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#:::(prefix:List[A]):List[A]).

Note this special thing: when a method name ends in `:`, then Scala calls the method on the value on the right, passing the value on the left as an argument (with other methods whose names do not end with `:`, it's the other way around). The API docs say "Adds the elements of a given list in front of this list", that's because the `:::` method is called on `List(3,4,5)`, with `List(1,2)` as an argument; so `List(1,2)` is added in front of `List(3,4,5)`.